# How to add a second summary and a vertical line to your graph in a forestplot?

Tags: r, summary, r-forestplot

I am building a forestplot with the forestplot package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/forestplot.pdf) and have come a long way but I am now stuck on 2 final issues. I am hoping someone here might have helpful advice.

I am presenting the results for my meta-analysis in a forestplot that looks a lot like this example and is based on the script provided here;
[example fp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8CPA.png)
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html

There's 2 things that I cannot seem to figure out

1. I want a vertical line in the graph for the mean OR
   (fp_add_lines is adding a line to the total figure not just the graph part of the figure)
2. I want to add a second summary to the plot/graph
   (fp_append_row works perfect for the first summary, but not for a second)

**Anyone here who has experience with this package and knows how to tackle these issues?**

I naturally prefer a clean script and not a work-around (overlaying 2 plots to get the vertical line, or manually adding a symbol for the second summary).

Many thanks in advance!